# Pyglet: create image, set pixels, draw antialiased lines and save to file

Tags: python, pyglet

I want to create a (grayscale) `image` from a matrix, `draw` some lines into it and save it to a `file`.

In `PIL` it looks like this:

```
im = Image.new("RGB", (len(matrix), len(matrix[0])))
for x in range(0, len(matrix)):
    for y in range(0, len(matrix[0])):
        cl = int(matrix[x][y] * 255.0 / float(max_value))
        im.putpixel((x, y), (cl, cl, cl))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon((off_x, off_y, off_x + a, off_y, off_x + x, off_y + y), outline="#FF0000")
im.save("pix.png")
```

Sadly, PIL's lines look ugly since it does not support anti-aliasing.
`Pyglet` is full of different surfaces, textures and images and I don't really know where to start. So how would a simple way to do this in pyglet look like? Or may there be any easier way?